# Is there a way to include go in dymanic SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

```
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @dbName VARCHAR(100)--  
SET @dbName = 'somedbname'--    
SET @sql = 'USE [' + @dbName + ']' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
SET @sql = @sql + 'GO' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)--  Print the command
EXEC (@sql)
```

When I run this it gives error Incorrect syntax near 'GO' has someone found workaround to this?

Requirement : I need to include stored procedure creation in switched database.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: database other than currently script executing database. I need to create stored procedure in that database.

Comment: I mean which RDBMS?  SQL Server? MySQL? Oracle?

Comment: If you can't be bothered to take time to ask a question fully, why should we take the time to answer when it's probably incomplete or doesn't ask the correct question

Comment: @gbn I was in a release people were asking for it, tried to get help from SO users as quickly as i can. sad about minus comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GO` is [not a SQL statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) - it is **a command recognized by the SQL Server utilities** (e.g. sqlcmd, osql, SQL Server Management Studio code editor).

However, you can [change the database without the `GO` command](http://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/3974/database-use-issues-with-dynamic-sql).